Howler.js: How to resume audio playback from paused position instead of restarting from beginning?
I'm using Howler.js to play audio files in my web application. I have a play and pause button, and when I click the pause button, the audio pauses correctly. However, when I click the play button again, the audio restarts from the beginning instead of resuming from the paused position.
I've tried storing the current playback position when pausing the audio, but I'm not sure how to use that value to resume playback from the correct position. Can anyone help me figure out how to modify my code to achieve this?
Here's my code:
// import dependancies
import { Howl } from "howler/dist/howler";
import { beat_src } from "./player_beat_src";

// select DOM element
let play_button = document.getElementById("audio_player_play_button");
let pause_button = document.getElementById("audio_player_pause_button");

/**
 * @typedef {Howl} sound that handle the current beat
 *
 **/
export let sound = {};
/**
 * @function play_beat() function to play beats.
 * Verify if a beat url is given.If it is,then play the beat,
 * else then output  the error message.
 * @var beat_id that store the id of the current beat to perform actions on it
 * @var time that store the current playing time
 **/

let beat_id;
let time;
let previous_beat;
let current_beat;

export function play_beat() {
    // if a beat is already playing
    current_beat = beat_src.src;
    if (beat_id && previous_beat !== current_beat) {
        sound.stop(beat_id);
        sound.unload();
        sound = new Howl({
            src: [beat_src.src],
            html5: true,
        });
        beat_id = sound.play();

        console.log(
            "sound already play then changed\n",
            "previous_beat :",
            previous_beat,
            "\n",
            "current_beat :",
            current_beat
        );
        previous_beat = current_beat;
    }
    // if a beat is paused
    else if (beat_id && previous_beat === current_beat) {
        time = sound.seek(beat_id);
        sound.seek(time, beat_id);
        beat_id = sound.play(beat_id);

        paused = false;
        console.log(
            "sound was paused then play  \n",
            "previous_beat :",
            previous_beat,
            "\n",
            "current_beat :",
            current_beat,
            "\n",
            time
        );
    }
    // if this is the first beat to be played
    else {
        sound = new Howl({
            src: [beat_src.src],
            html5: true,
        });
        beat_id = sound.play();
        previous_beat = current_beat = beat_src.src;
        console.log(
            "sound initialization \n",
            "previous_beat :",
            previous_beat,
            "\n",
            "current_beat :",
            current_beat
        );
    }
}

/**
 * @function pause_beat() function to pause beats.
 * Verify if a beat url is given.If it is,then pause the beat,
 * else then output  the error message.
 **/
export function pause_beat() {
    sound.pause(beat_id);
}

//
play_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    play_beat();
});

pause_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    pause_beat();
});



i realised that this is browser specific,its works fine on firefox,now how to do it in chrome?

i solved it by changing "html5" to "false".
sound = new Howl({
            src: [beat_src.src],
            html5: false,
        });

